# Mix expanded properties from Select-Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, select, properties

```
Get-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```

> ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands

---

Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}

I want to expand ExportedCommands and print Name by each one.

```
          Name                             ExportedCmdlets
  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility            Add-Member
  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility            Add-Type
  Microsoft.Powershell.Utility            Clear-Variable
  Microsoft.Powershell.Utility            Compare-Object
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the problem you're attempting in general, but you should be able to get this list from `Get-Command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a nested foreach loop to iterate over the exported cmdlets. If you look at the type of object that property is, you'll see it's a dictionary.

```
Get-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ExportedCmdlets | Get-Member
}

TypeName: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo, System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]
```

Since the keys and the names are the same in this case, you can use either.

```
Get-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($cmdlet in $_.ExportedCmdlets.keys){
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name   = $_.Name
            Cmdlet = $cmdlet
        }
    }
}
```

Output (truncated)

```
Name                         Cmdlet                
----                         ------                
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility Add-Member            
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility Add-Type              
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility Clear-Variable        
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility Compare-Object
```